# How to determine the maximum of a sine graph with only 2 known points?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I'm literally stuck at *A*. The answer is ($\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{3}{2}$) but I don't know how to get it, most significantly because I don't know how to find the answer from the points when the equation doesn't have an amplitude coefficient or a period coefficient-- the graph has just been shifted. And because the graph has been shifted, the period isn't divided into 2 equal halves anymore-- the curve between $0$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ is bigger and taller than the one between $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ and $2\pi$.

**What I've tried:** I realized that the period would still be $2\pi$ and the amplitude would still be 1, meaning the height of the entire graph would be 2. I understood how to figure out the minimum point as $\frac{5\pi}{3}$, but I don't know how to get A after that. I assumed that because the difference between $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ is one-half of the difference between $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ and 0, that the size of the curve on the left is twice the size of the curve on the right. But beyond that, I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have the function $f(x) = \sin(x-k) + c$

And looking at the graph we know 2 things:

$
f(0) = 0 \\
f \left ( \frac{4\pi}{3} \right ) = 0
$

Using the first we have

$$
0 = \sin(-k) + c = -\sin(k) + c \Rightarrow c = \sin(k)
$$

Now using the second and substituting the value we just got for $c$ we have
$$
\sin \left ( \frac{4\pi}{3} -k \right ) + \sin(k) = 0 \\
$$

Now recall the identity
$$
\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) = 2\sin \left ( \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \right ) \cos \left ( \frac{\alpha - \beta}{2} \right )
$$

This leaves us with
$$
\begin{align}
2\sin \left ( \frac{2\pi}{3} \right ) \cos \left ( \frac{2\pi}{3} - k \right ) &= 0 \\
\cos \left ( \frac{2\pi}{3} - k \right ) &= 0 \\
\cos^{-1} \left ( \cos \left ( \frac{2\pi}{3} - k \right ) \right ) &= \cos^{-1}(0) \\
\frac{2\pi}{3} - k &= \frac{\pi}{2} \\
k &= \frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align}
$$

So we have $k = \frac{\pi}{6} \text{ and } c = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: is there a way to do this without the identity you mentioned?

Comment: also how do you find the coordinates of A then?

Comment: @bluesky  bthmas obtained the equation $$f(x) = \sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\right) + \frac{1}{2}$$  Since $\sin t = 1$ when $t = \pi/2$, the maximum value of $f(x)$ occurs when $$x - \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$